# I cant fetch the image from xampp database

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f4jZ.png)

I am trying to upload an image to database but when I try to retrieve it only it's name appears.
The code is in the above link.

Comment: Please add a screenshot from your database and post the actual code instead of a picture.

Comment: You're saving the filename instead of the actual file.

Comment: Tag for showing image is `<img src="" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, when you post a form, the content of the uploaded files are not in the $_POST value, they are in $_FILES.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php , and keep in mind all you want to do is read the content of the uploaded file (maybe with a file_get_contents($_FILES[...]['tmp_name']) to store it in your database.

Hope it helps =)

PS: in your database, put your column in BLOB format, it's better for storing binary data